# Should I store facebook friends list in firebase database?

Tags: database, swift, facebook-graph-api, firebase, social-networking

I am trying to create a social feature allows friend to interact with each other in the app. The friends network will be retrieved from Facebook. The coding is done up to that part (written in Swift but I think this is a generic scenario regardless of programming language). My question is should I store the friends list in Firebase as well? One benefit i see is that the app doesn't need to inquire Facebook API each time it needs to display the friends list.

If storing the list in Firebase (or locally), what's the best way to sync with the Facebook to ensure the list is always updated?

Comment: you should store it in the db. the data might be useful and facebook data is not under your control. To keep in sync store the time stamp and then sync every few hours/day whichever suits you

Comment: that's a good point. i assume sync task is best to be run within the app when it's launched?

Comment: @Shubhank , can you convert your comment as the answer to be accepted? thanks